# Dart Flutter: make non constant property constant

Tags: flutter, dart, properties, constants

I have this object

```
class Foo {
  Color color;

  Foo({this.color = Colors.red});
}
```

I really need to be able to update the color property so it can't be constant. But I need it to be constant for flutter_local_notifications

```
const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('foo',
            'foo', 'foo',
            color: Foo.color, // this has to be constant
        );
```

So how can I make `Foo.color` constant?

```
const Color color = const Foo.color; // throws error
```

Comment: I would recommend you to directly use Color value `Colors.red` instead of using `Foo.color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, Dart constant needs to be initialized with:

- A value of a primitive type
- A literal value derived by using only basic or bitwise operators
- A constant constructor

This is why you need to use the `Colors.red`, which is a constant when initializing the `AndroidNotificationDetails`. Other options is to use the `final` keyword instead of `const`, which still make your `AndroidNotificationDetails` variable immutable and doesn't require a constant value when initiating.